# SQL: remove duplicate rows across columns

Tags: sql, sqlite, duplicates

I have a table which is loaded into sqlite in the following format:

```
player1 player2 player1Probability player2Probability
John    Peter   0.6                0.4
Peter   John    0.4                0.6
Mary    Bob     0.8                0.2
Bob     Mary    0.2                0.8
```

As you can see, there are duplicates across different columns. The first two rows are essentially identical in the data they provide: We can see that John has a 0.6 probability and Peter has 0.4 from the first row, while the second row just duplicates this information.

Is there any way to remove the duplicated rows through an SQL query?

Answer (score -1):

This is how I'd do it in MySQL, I'm hoping it can be done similarly in sqlite.

```
DELETE t1.*
FROM YourTable AS t1
JOIN YourTable AS t2 
ON t1.player1 = t2.player2 
    AND t1.player2 = t2.player1 
    AND t1.player1 > t1.player2
```

Another way:

```
DELETE FROM YourTable AS t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM YourTable AS t2
              WHERE t1.player1 = t2.player2
                 AND t1.player2 = t1.player1
                 AND t2.player1 < t1.player2)
```

Comment: OK, I've added another try.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I tried the second way, but I'm not getting any rows deleted. Any further help will be much appreciated